# Panes inside kendoSplitter doesn't respect "box-sizing:border-box" property

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, kendo-ui

I am using kendoSplitter to create a page layout with 2 panes.
Setting the first pane size as "100px" and the remaining space for 2nd pane.

Set the padding for the panes as "5px" and set the box-sizing as "border-box".
So,expected the width of pane1 including padding is "100px"
But on page load, it applied padding on top of 100px,making the width as 110px and leading to scrollbar.

```
$('#splitter').kendoSplitter({
    panes:[
    {collapsible:true,size:'100px'},
    {collapsible:true,resizable:true}
    ]
});
```

jsFiddler for this case:
http://jsfiddle.net/nagakiran/xmTJF/

But if I apply the padding after initializing kendoSplitter,it works as in this fiddler.
http://jsfiddle.net/nagakiran/hPVWf/1/

Looks it's a bug in kendoUI or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by adding a flag in kendoSplitter which modifies the way width is assigned to splitter panes. If this flag is set,it will reduce the width that's assigned to each pane by the "padding-left+padding-right" specified for that pane.

After that found a simple solution of creating wrapper div inside each splitter-pane and set "box-sizing:border-box" and "padding:10px", which worked without issues.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is a bug. Maybe an *undocumented feature* or a *side-effect*. It seems that is a question about the order on how things are executed.
Remember that you HTML is "decorated" by KendoUI widgets so what you have defined as `splitter1` is not just your `div` but more things (the decoration).

When you style it after invoking `kendoSplitter` you are actually re-decorating the result of KendoUI decoration. Since `kendoSplitter` sets the `width` of your pane to a fixed width, the padding does not add extra space.

But when you use the CSS, it *runs* simultaneously to `kendoSplitter` and when it asks for the size, it gets the *wrong* size.

Should KendoUI be smarter? Maybe but it's actually pretty hard guessing what CSS are going to do and apply a counter action before the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Kendo has issues with `box-sizing: borderbox`. [This post](http://feedback.kendoui.com/forums/127393-kendo-ui-feedback/suggestions/3694827-fix-box-sizing-for-kendo-controls-if-set-in-base-c) may help.